# Assign values from one cell to another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I am trying to assign a values from cell B1 to cell C1..
for example, B1 has the characters 12$%Qs and C1 has eR23*^
so I would want 1 from B1 to equal e from C1, then 2 from B1 to equal R from C1 and so on..any help would be great ive been stuck and not used to using excel

Comment: Could you show sample data of what you mean?

Comment: What is the motivation behind this task? There might be other ways to achieve your ultimate goal. If, however, you cling on to the above, what should trigger the copying of characters, what if either cell has more characters than the other one?

Answer (score 0):

If this is for password hashing, I'd suggest using something like hashapass instead of an Excel sheet.

Regardless, you'd first two columns with the conversions side by side, say, in A2:B30.

You'd then use *offset-match* or *vlookup* for each letter and join together.

With 1st text in D1:

First letter:

```
=offset(b1,match( left(d1, 1),a2:a30,0),0)
```

Second letter:

```
=offset(b1,match(right( left(d1, 2),1),a2:a30,0),0)
```

See how the *right* and *left* functions are used to isolate the letter you are changing each time.

Joining those two together with & would look like:

```
=offset(b1,match( left(d1, 1),a2:a30,0),0) & offset(b1,match(right( left(d1, 2),1),a2:a30,0),0)
```

Continue concatenating formulae like that until you have the right number of letters, incrementing the number in the *left* function each time.